# Laravel how can I do a login for different types of users without doing roles?

Tags: laravel

I developed some systems with laravel before, but only with the default user doing the login, now I have to develop a new system with 3 types of users, each one connected to different tables in the database doing different things, in What it could The investigation can be done with roles connected to the users table and this does not help me and my database model is full of recursive relationships that I have been asked to avoid at all costs.

How can I manage different types of user by login without resorting to using roles?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission). Simple and the doc is very clear. Regarding the database, laravel-permission has a [roles table](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/master/database/migrations/create_permission_tables.php.stub) that consists of the roles and another table with permissions so you don't need to create a table for each role. Give it a try!